# How the server receive data asynchronously?

Tags: node.js, http, bun

I recently program some code on creating a HTTP server with Node.js. But I am having a hard time understand what happens under the hood, especially in terms of the way Node.js receiving body data. From my point, the client send the HTTP request message together with Request line, Request Headers, and Request body just with the only one request. So I think the body data would be received together with Request Line and Request Headers. While we can receive the body asychronously in Node.js, so my question is does Nodejs store the body data in its cache temporarily after its getting the Request message?

For instance, Here's a HTTP client using bun

```js
// client.js with bun
const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: 'Hello, Server! This is Client.'
});
```

I capture this HTTP request message with WireShark, something like this
[image]

It proved that the Request Line, Request Headers and Request body were sent together just with only one HTTP request.
One request means that It necessary for the server to receive the Request message synchronously, otherwise it would be gone. But we can receive body data asynchrounously in Node.js, even after 10 seconds delay. Here the server code:

```js
// server.mjs with node.js
import { createServer } from 'node:http';

async function delay(timeout) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
  });
}

createServer(async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.url);
  console.log(req.method);
  console.log(req.headers['content-type']);

  setTimeout(async () => {
    const chunkArr = [];
    req.on('data', chunk => {
      chunkArr.push(chunk);
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
      console.log(Buffer.concat(chunkArr).toString());
    });
  }, 1000);

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    await delay(1000);
    console.log(i + 1);
  }
}).listen(3000);
```

Where did the body data store in that 10 seconds? Was it storing in the cache of Node.js?

Comment: Your server code is fundamentally broken, there's no `res.end` so that the response is never sent back. As for the question, the incoming stream is held in the request object.

Comment: The body data is buffered by Node.js (or some library used by Node.js internally), for sure.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the `delay` function is a **microtask** which will run before the `setTimeout` function. That's why the body is printed after 10 delays. Details can be found if you google "Event loop in javascript".

In addition, the body data is referenced in the function in a `setTimeout` **macrotask** so that it will be stored in the execution context. To find more details about data storage in js, please read [Javascript Runtime: JS Engine, Event Loop, Call Stack, Execution Contexts, Heap, and Queues](https://itnext.io/javascript-runtime-js-engine-event-loop-call-stack-execution-contexts-heap-and-queues-4826d064ad76).

Comment: Did Node.js cache the body data?

Comment: Hmmm, I would say no. It is stored in the memory of Javascript runtime in nodejs. It was a mistake to say yes, and I will fix it.